# Why eventhandler function in document.ready works but doesn't work when taken out?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, mouseover, eventhandler

I am new to Javascript and I am wondering on the behavior below.

Consider the **working code** below:

```
 <div><br/><strong>Click Me!</strong></div>   
 <script>

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('div').mouseenter(function(){
           $(this).fadeTo('fast',1);
        });

        $('div').mouseleave(function(){
           $(this).fadeTo('fast',0.5); 
        });

    });

 </script>
```

But this one **does not work**:

```
 <div onmouseover="fade()"><br/><strong>Click Me!</strong></div>   
 <script>

    $(document).ready(function(){

        $('div').mouseleave(function(){
           $(this).fadeTo('fast',0.5); 
        });

    });

    function fade(){
        $(this).fadeTo('fast',1);
    }
 </script>
```

Why is the second one not working when all I did was use inline eventhandler and function?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why would you want to switch to using the old `onXyz` attributes?!

Comment: `mouseover` != `mouseenter`!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, I wouldn't do this. Switching from using modern event handling to `onXyz` attributes is a bit backward. See below the fold for more.

But answering the question of why it didn't work: `this` within the call to `fade` in your second example is not the div (it's the global object, aka `window` on browsers). You'd have to change your `onmouseover` to:

```
onmouseover="fade.call(this)"
```

...for `this` to be the div during the call.

(Separately, note that you used `onmouseover` in the second code block but `mouseenter` in your first code block. I've left it as `onmouseover`, but you probably wanted `onmouseneter` instead.)

Example:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('div').mouseleave(function(){
    $(this).fadeTo('fast',0.5); 
  });

});

function fade(){
  $(this).fadeTo('fast',1);
}
```

```html
<div onmouseover="fade.call(this)"><br/><strong>Click Me!</strong></div>   
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Or alternately, just pass `this` in as an argument and change `fade` to use it:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('div').mouseleave(function(){
    $(this).fadeTo('fast',0.5); 
  });

});

function fade(element){
  $(element).fadeTo('fast',1);
}
```

```html
<div onmouseover="fade(this)"><br/><strong>Click Me!</strong></div>   
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

But again, I wouldn't use an `onXyz` attribute; if you don't want the handlers in a `ready` callback, they don't need to be, but that doesn't mean you have to switch to using attributes for event hookup. Instead:

```
$('div').mouseleave(function(){
  $(this).fadeTo('fast',0.5); 
});
$('div').mouseenter(function(){
  $(this).fadeTo('fast',1); 
});
```

Example:

```js
$('div').mouseleave(function(){
  $(this).fadeTo('fast',0.5); 
});
$('div').mouseenter(function(){
  $(this).fadeTo('fast',1); 
});
```

```html
<div><br/><strong>Click Me!</strong></div>   
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -2):

You use `document.ready` because you don't know if the nodes you're trying to effect have been rendered yet.

Scripts are executed in-order on the page. So if you have more `div`s below your script definition they're not going to match in `$("div")`.

Since scripts are typically included in the header, you totally need `document.ready` if you want JavaScript to see all the nodes initially.

In your example you don't need `document.ready` per se. The error is elsewhere.

---

```
<div>1</div>
<script>
  console.log($("div").length); // 1
  $(document).ready(function () {
    console.log($("div").length); // 2
  });
</script>
<div>2</div>
```

Comment: While what you say is true, the div the OP is operating on clearly **is** rendered, from the content of the code block in their question. So this is unrelated to the problem.